# Python: Use of for loops to iterate through a list of categories and sub-categories. TypeError: must be str, not list

Tags: python, list, loops, screen-scraping

I have a sample list of car makes and models to iterate through and carry out code on.

```
...
makes = ['Ford', 'Audi']
ford_models = ['C-MAX', 'Focus']
audi_models = ['A3', 'A4']
models = [ford_models, audi_models]

base_url = "https://www.donedeal.ie/cars/"
```

Program code:

```
#Go through a make in the list along with all its models 
#and then move onto the second make and all its models and so on..

for make in makes: 
    for model in models:
       for response in range(0,58,29):
            headers = {
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
            response = requests.get(base_url + make + "/" + model + "?start=" + str(response), headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

            ...
```

I want the program to first go to Ford as the make and firstly run all the code for C-MAX, then go back into the loop and run all the code for Focus. After it finishes with Focus, I want it to change the make to Audi, and go through the Audi models (first A3 and then A4). I made an attempt but getting an error:

```
response = requests.get(base_url + make + "/" + model + "?start=" + str(response), headers=headers)
TypeError: must be str, not list
```

How can I fix the error and achieve this using for loops?

Comment: You get the error because variable `model` is a `list`, and you cannot concatenate lists and strings together.

Comment: @Niko are you sure about your range choice? Because `range(0,58,29)` is just `(0, 29)` not `(0, 29, 58)`..

Comment: @Guimoute I suppose yes, ?start=0 is the start on page 1, 58 is the end of page 2 and 29 is the step it takes each page ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate problem is that `model` is a list of models, not the name of an individual model.  You neglected to do any basic tracing of your operation.

```
for make in makes: 
    for model in models:
        print (make, model)
```

will show you the logic problem.

You need to key your models to the make.  Use a dict:

```
make_model {
    'Ford': ['C-MAX', 'Focus'],
    'Audi':  ['A3', 'A4']
}

for make in make_model:
    for model in make_model[make]:
```

*This* will iterate your make/model pairings as you want.  I expect you can finish from here.

Answer (score 3):

`models` is list of lists, not the list of combined models.

```
models = ford_models + audi_models
```

(Though as @Prune points out, you probably don't want to combine the models, but rather use a separate make-specific list at each iteration. I won't both repeating that here.)

Also, let `requests` build the URL for you, rather than hand-coding the query string

```
url_template = "https://www.donedeal.ie/cars/{}/{}"
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
}

for make, model in itertools.product(makes, models):
    url = url_template.format(make, model)
    response = requests.get(url, params={'start': str(response)}, header=headers)
```